# Rendering Video using XCDYouTubeKit and swift

Tags: ios, swift

Please bear with me as I have been trying to program in iOs using swift for a week now and at the moment I am stuck on an error. I need some insight with what is wrong with what I am doing.

Screenshot of Storyboard and .swift file
[image]

Screenshot of my error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna guess you have resolved it. Usually that error comes when you deleted an IBOutlet from the interface side of code but you still have it left behind in the the storyboard. Delete the "test" IBOutlet from the storyboard and that should fix it.